# Karma testing an Angular directive with template: require(...), and Webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I'm trying to wrap my head around Webpack, Angular and Karma... especially regarding html templates.

For example, I have a directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        ...
    },
    template: require('../partials/dashboard.html'),
    link: link
};
```

Thanks to webpack config html-loader, I'm able to inline the html into the directive:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'html'
},
```

Everything works fine after being bundled by webpack.

Now, the issue is that I want to test this directive... But it complains because it cannot find /my/karma/path/partials/dashboard.html.js . So I add ng-html2js prepocessor to Karma, but now it complains that:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined ... at line 5
```

The generated dashboard.html.js looks like this:

```
(function(module) {
try {
  module = angular.module('templates');
} catch (e) {
  module = angular.module('templates', []);
}
```

So it actually finds the file, goes to line 5 and doesn't know what angular is...

Can someone point me to a working example that's similar to what I'm trying to do? Or give me some advice? Thanks!

Also - I'm not hung up on the solution with html-loader... But trying also ng-cache-loader and others, I end up with the same issue...

Edit: karma.conf.js:

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '../..',

        files: [
            // external libraries
            { pattern: 'main/themes/node_modules/requirejs/require.js', included: false },
            { pattern: 'main/themes/node_modules/angular/angular.js', included: false },
            (...)
            // html templates
            { pattern: 'main/webapp/static/bla/bla/partials/*.html', included: false },
            // test cases
            { pattern: 'test/webapp/static/bla/bla/**/*.spec.js', included: false },
            // main require config for testing
            'test/webapp/static/bla/bla/scripts/test-main.js'
        ],
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs', 'sinon'],
        preprocessors: {
            'main/webapp/static/bla/bla/partials/*.html': 'ng-html2js'
        },
        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            moduleName: 'templates'
        },    
        (... some other configs...)

    })
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your karma config file ? it suspect that `angular` is not embedded.

Comment: @Zakaria - I added the config. There's also a test-main config for requirejs... That's why I was more asking if I can receive any tips or examples on how to do this, because I have a lot of old configurations (migrating to webpack) that I want to get rid off...